# Base change of affine group schemes with respect to Frobenius map.

Tags: algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is an affine group scheme over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$. Let $G^{(p)}$ be the base change of $G$ with respect to the Frobenius map of $k$ (i.e. $p$-th power map). Is there any easy way to see $G$ and $G^{(p)}$ are canonically isomorphic?

Comment: No, since they're not generally isomorphic at all.

Comment: [I assume you intend for the isomorphism to be of group schemes over $k$.]

Comment: In Waterhouse's book Intro. to Affine Group schemes, Chapter 11 Exercise 12 (c), it says that they are canonically isomorphic, but the  given map is not k-linear, so I am not sure about the result.

Comment: I recommend ignoring that exercise, since such an assertion is rather misleading.  (The point is that the Frobenius is an automorphism of $k$, from which the isomorphism claim in his weak sense is obvious.)